# Triger Event after Queue Finished

Tags: php, laravel

I want to Trigger an event after my Queue Finish and send $ids variable with Pusher
I have seen that most of the Suggestions are using Queue::after which I don't know how to work with I am stuck with that for 3 days, I have already installed the pusher I only need to send the $ids variable after the job is finished.
and here is my code :

```
    class ShipWithAramex implements ShouldQueue
{  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
     @return void
    public $data;
    public $type;
    public $auth_id;
    public $validatedOrders;
    public function __construct($data,$type,$validatedOrders,$auth_id)
    {
        $this->data=$data;
        $this->type=$type;
        $this->auth_id=$auth_id;
        $this->validatedOrders=$validatedOrders;
     
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {    
      try {
            //code...

        $ids=[];
        $armx = new Aramex();
    
        foreach ($this->data as $key => $order)
        {
       
            array_push($ids,$order->id);
            $address = $order->address;
            $city = $order->city;
            $zip_code = $order->zip_code;
            $country = "MA";
            if($order->country=="Morocco")
                $order->country = 'MA'; 
            if($city != "nc"){
                $nt = Note::where('note', 'like', 'Order added auto from woocommerce %')
                          ->where('order_id', $order->id)->first();
                if (@$nt !== null)
                {
                    $note = trim($nt->note);
                    $order_id = explode(' ', $note) [5];
                    $website = new WPApi();
                }

                if ($order->store_id != null)
                {
                    $wh = Webhook::find($order->store_id);
                }
                else
                {
                    $wh = Webhook::where('user_id', $this->auth_id)
                        ->orderByDesc("id")
                        ->first();
                }
                $cnx=null;
                if ($wh!=null) {
                    $cnx = $website->connect($wh->url, $wh->ck, $wh->cs);
                    $tst = (object)$cnx->get('orders/' . $order_id);
                    $bill = (object)($tst->billing);
                    $address = $bill->address_1.' '.$bill->address_2;
                    $city = $bill->city;
                    $zip_code = $bill->postcode;
                    $country = $bill->country;
                }
 
                if ($this->validatedOrders)
                {
                    foreach ($this->validatedOrders as $key => $line)
                    {
                        $tofix = json_decode($line);
                        if ($order->id == $tofix->order)
                        {
                            $order->city = $tofix->city;
                            $order->address = $tofix->address;
                            $order->country = $tofix->country;
                            $order->zip_code = $tofix->zip;
                        }
                    }
                }
                $toUpdate['Billing']=array('postcode'=>$order->zip_code,
                                           'address'=>$order->address,
                                           'address_1'=>$order->address,
                                           'city'=>$order->city);
                if ($cnx) {
                    $respo=$cnx->put('orders/'.$order_id,$toUpdate);
                }
            }
           
            $result = $armx->create($order, $this->type);
            
                $url = $result['doc'];
                $file_name = basename($url);
                if (file_put_contents(storage_path("app/public/aramex/" . $order->id . ".pdf") , file_get_contents($url)))
                {
                    $payment = 'P';
                    if ($this->type == 'CODS')
                    {
                        $payment = $this->type;
                    }
                    $PDFParser = new Parser();
                    $pdf = $PDFParser->parseFile(storage_path('app/public/aramex/' . $order['id'] . '.pdf'));
                    $text = $pdf->getText();
                    $destination = explode(' ', explode(PHP_EOL, $text) [3]) [0];
                    EndOfday::updateOrCreate(['order_id' => $order->id],
                                             ['date' => date('Y-m-d') ,
                                              'type' => $payment,
                                              'country' => $order->country,
                                              'city' => $order->city,
                                              'postcode' => (isset($order->zip_code)) ? $order->zip_code : "00",
                                              'destination' => $destination,
                                              'user_id' => $this->auth_id ]);
                                                
                    $br_code = BrCode::create(['br_code' => $result['track'], 'status' => 0]);
                    Note::create(['note' => 'This Order is Shipped By Aramex. Tracking: ' . $result['track'],
                                  'order_id' => $order->id,
                                  'user_id' => $this->auth_id ]);
                                  
                    $ordBr = Order::find($order->id)->update(['br_code_id' => $br_code->id]);
                }
            }

        

 
        }
        catch (\Throwable $th) {
            
            $this->failed($th);
        }




    }

    public function failed($exception)
    {
        
        dd($exception->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you checkout de documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#job-events?

You can add the Queue::after hook in your AppServiceProvider and trigger an event in there.

You may inspect the $event which is accepted in the closure to get more information about the job that just has finished.

Comment: I have checked the documentation but I don't know how to use is